# Function Pointer help/ Pointer from integer

Tags: c, pointers, binary-tree, function-pointers

So I'm doing an assignment where we need to pass functions we've made ourselves into a library provided for us.

```
Tree * createBinTree(int (*comparePointer) (TreeDataTypePtr data1,      
TreeDataTypePtr data2), void (*destroyPointer) (TreeDataTypePtr));
```

Is the code I've been provided.
My function pointer for the comparePointer is

```
int(*compStr)(void *, void *) = &compareName;
```

Compare is

```
int compareName(void * rest1, void * rest2);
```

But when I pass it through like so

```
Tree * myTree = createBinTree((compstr)(str1,str2),die(str1));
```

I only get an error on compstr which is "passing argument 1 of createBinTree makes pointer from integer without a cast" and "expected 'int (*)(void *, void *) but argument is of type int.

Comment: Because you need to pass only the function names: `Tree * myTree = createBinTree(compstr, die);`

Comment: So that worked, but I'm not sure how to use the variables now

Comment: The point of this API, that you are *not supposed* to call these functions.

Comment: That makes so much more sense now, thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the function, not call the function and pass the return value:

```
Tree* myTree = createBinTree( compstr , die );
```

But this is still not correct. The types of `compstr` and `die` must be compatible with the parameter types of the function `createBinTree`:

```
int(*compStr)( TreeDataTypePtr , TreeDataTypePtr ) = &compareName;
```

in which case, `compareName` must be a function of the same type. The same goes for `die`.

---

Note that only casting function pointers to the compatible type will cause undefined behavior when they are used to call the function. The original type of the function pointer must be compatible with the type used to call the function. This **will cause undefined behavior**:

```
int(*compStr)(void *, void *) = &compareName;
Tree* myTree = createBinTree( ( int(*)(TreeDataTypePtr,TreeDataTypePtr ) )compstr , die );
```

Comment: How am I supposed to use the values then?

Comment: @Bipop I don't understand the question. `TreeDataTypePtr` is defined isn't it?

Comment: compstr and die are compatible, but this is the first time I'm using function pointers so I don't really understand how just passing the functions achieves much.

TreeDataTypePtr is defined in this line



                                                          typedef void * TreeDataTypePtr

Comment: @Bipop It depends on what type is `TreeDataTypePtr `, which you didn't provide. Usually you would cast the pointers. This loses type safety of course.

Comment: Okay I think I kind of understand. Sorry for the confusion and really appreciate the help!

Comment: @Bipop Just don't cast the function pointers themselves. You will cause undefined behavior in this case.

Comment: The createBinTree() method you were given expects a function that has two arguments of type TreeDataTypePtr, but your compareName is declared to take two void* arguments. Change your compareName() method to take two TreeDataTypePtr arguments.

Comment: @FredK You should move that comment to the question otherwise Bipop won't see it.